# Binding interpolated data to the existing element of an array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a working demo of elements being dropped in and showing up there top, left values. I have also implemented the removal (deleting) of dropped items and bringing it to and fro from the existing blocks to the dropped area. However, I am stuck with some small issues.

On moving the already existing box (existingDroppedItemZoneIn array) within the area it's top, left values are not binded, I am not able to figure out how to bind them (though it is similar to the other *ngFor).

After removal of the box from the grey area when I again drop the box back into the grey area it shows the previous retained top, left value initially which it should not.

And moreover on moving the existing box (existingDroppedItemZoneIn array boxes) also starts changing the top and left values of the box that has been dropped from outside(boxes tied to dropzone1 array)

NOTE: Please click on ToGetExistingItem button to see the existing box as well as the already present boxes, then above issues can be reproduced.

```
move(box: string, toList: string[]): void { 
    box = this.currentBoxFloorZone;
    let objTemp:any = {
        pos:[]
      };
    objTemp.dis = this.currentBoxFloorZone;
    for(var i=0; i < this.topLeft.length; i++){
        objTemp.pos.push(this.topLeft[i]);
    } 
    //this.removeBox(box, this.dropzone1);
    this.removeBox(box,this.roomsFloorZoneIn);
    toList.push(objTemp);   
}

removeBox(item: string, list, flag:boolean = false) {
        if (list.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
            list.splice(list.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
        if(flag){
            console.log("wassupppp");
            this.roomsFloorZoneIn.push(item);
        }

}
```

hello.component.html

```
 <div id="toget"
      class="dropzone"
      [ngStyle]="{'position': 'relative'}"
      appMovableArea 
      appDropzone
     (drop)="move(currentBox, dropzone1)">

 <div class="box"
      appMovable
      *ngFor="let existingZone of existingDroppedItemZoneIn"
      [ngStyle] = "{'position': 'absolute', 
       'top.%':existingZone.spans[1], 'left.%':existingZone.spans[0]}">

         {{ existingZone.main }}

    <span style="display: none">{{existingZone.spans[0]}}</span>
    <span style="display: none">{{existingZone.spans[1]}}</span>
    <span(click)="removeBox(existingZone,existingDroppedItemZoneIn,true)">
        x
    </span>

 </div>

 <div class="box" *ngFor="let box of dropzone1" appDroppable 
 (dragStart)="currentBox = box" appMovable>

    {{ box.dis.dis }}

    <span style="display: none">{{box.pos[0]}}</span>
    <span style="display: none">{{box.pos[1]}}</span>
    <span (click)="removeBox(box,dropzone1,true)">x</span>

 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
 <hello
  [urlFloorZone]='url'
  [roomsFloorZone]='zonesToBepassed' 
  [currentBoxFloorZone]='currentBox'
  [existingDroppedItem] = 'droppeditem'
  (floorToParent)="updateFloorRooms($event)>
 </hello>
```

app.component

```
updateFloorRooms(e){
   this.rooms.push(e.dis)
}
```

The working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfgwi1?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) with actual issues

Comment: The updated demo , on further inputs by @ShashankVivek , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3whvic?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one questions which you have asked, I have fixed few but you need to work on your own to make it work properly.

Click on `ToGetExistingItem` button and then [try this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhnfxa?file=src/app/hello.component.html) :

1. Drag outside block `304`,`305`,`306` into grey box. It will change values
2. Try to move other blocks which were already added `301`,`302` . The value of recently added blocks wont change.
3. Your obj in `existingDroppedItemZoneIn` list is not added in `dropzone1` . that is why 
   `const movingBlockIndex = (this.dropzone1.indexOf(this.currentBox));` 
   is giving `-1`. And **hence the coordinates are not getting calculated**. That's why you are not getting position values in those blocks.

I have added

```
 (dragStart)="currentBox = existingZone"
```

and moved `this.will_draw` before `if` block.

```
  draw() {
    const movingBlockIndex = (this.dropzone1.indexOf(this.currentBox));
    this.will_draw = false;
    if (movingBlockIndex > -1) {
    .......... and so on
```

Comment: Thanks a ton before asking I had tried same but was notworking I might have missed out something,  now it is , however one last ,thing when I try doing the same thing for existingDroppedItemZoneIn , checking for index > -1 , the delete functionality doesn't work becoz the draw gets called everytime , how can I overcome that I 'll update the demo , please help,thanks

Comment: I have added updated demo in above post comment, thanks

Comment: @Enthu : ok, but what inputs you want from my end ?  I slightly fixed your issue in my answer and highlighted the mistakes you made.

Comment: thanks , the issue is when I try to follow the same approach for calculating top,left for existingDroppedItemZoneIn array similar to what we did for dropzone1 , the existingDroppedItemZoneIn start going outside of the dropzone area where as for dropzone1 array boxes they do not go out of the dropzone area (expectation is for existingDroppedItemZoneIn also should not go out of the dropzone grey area) and delete also stops working for existingDroppedItemZoneIn boxes.

Comment: Hi @ShashankVivek , can you please help me with the above issue if possible, thanks